# Pass argument (/verysilent) to application (subinstaller) executed from Pascal code in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin

I am trying to run the exe in silent mode, but I don't know how I can do it with the command line option. Below I have attached my script.

```
var progress:TOutputProgressWizardPage;

procedure DownloadFinished(downloadPage:TWizardPage);
var ErrorCode:integer;
begin
 if ShellExec('open', NewInstallerPath, '',
   ExtractFilePath(NewInstallerPath), SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode) then
   ExitProcess(1);
end;
```

Comment: Are you really just asking how to run an installer in silent mode from command line? How's the question related to the code you have posted and to the "geo" stuff?

Comment: Well this was your idea to find out where the user is from and guide them to that country exe but the issue is its not running the exe in /Verysilent mode since i dont know how i can do that with the code i have now. so i would like some help in running the exe using the command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arguments (like the `/verysilent`) go to the third parameter of the `ShellExec` function:

```pascal
if ShellExec('open', NewInstallerPath, '/verysilent',
     ExtractFilePath(NewInstallerPath), SW_SHOW, ewNoWait, ErrorCode) then
```